# Android debuggable=true with proguard is on

Tags: android, ant, proguard

As my project is too large, I need to run proguard in order to compile android successfully.

But when I set android:debuggable="true" in order for me to debug easily, it turn off proguard automatically. Is there any solution or workaround? Thank You

Comment: Why you need the progaurd ON for a debug build ?

Comment: I have explained in my first sentence. I would hit the opcode limit if I don't run proguard.  Here is the reference: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34019

Comment: If you use progaurd for debugging build, then its hard for you to debug the code since the progaurd rename the methods and variable names.

Comment: AFAIK, ADT will automatically turning on and off the Progaurd based on android:debuggable. So why dont you try to compile your code by yourself(manually).?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the exactly same problem. Luckily Google helped me out.

Now my `build.gradle`:

```
// ...
android {
    // ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.txt',
                    'proguard-rules.debug.txt'
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

`proguard-rules.debug.txt`:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

Worked for me. Hope it helps. ;-)